# ERROR: Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1

Tags: java, android

Hey I imported a project into my android studio and when I am trying to build the project it is showing this error into the error log:

> ERROR: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
>
> Required by:
>       project :app Search in build.gradle files

**build.gradle**

```
    android {

        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
            applicationId "com.ezs.boostantiv"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 26

            versionCode 1
            versionName "1"
        }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.2-beta.1.jar')
    //   compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'


    compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.kenumir:MaterialSettings:v.1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'

}
```

Please let me know how can I solve this issue. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: switch to androidx libs ( support to appcompat libs are stopped) and also use new gradle version change compile to implementation

Comment: Try to switch on the internet connection and retry the build. The IDE will try to download dependencies

Comment: @user2342558 Tried but still the same.

Comment: can u post project build.gradle

Comment: Upgrade your android studio first,then upgrade your build tools,"compile" for instance is depracated and replaced with "implementation",you can then switch to androidx libs

Comment: @HilaryMwape I already have the latest version of AS and plugin installed.

Comment: @AmitGoswami 

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: Then just add the androidx dependency: implementation ‘androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to Androidx Libraries,add below dependency

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

Comment: ERROR: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.jar

Required by:
    project :app

Answer (score 1):

migrate to androidx library. To map your current library to androidx, visit developer.android.com